# Using numbers for names of javascript object elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop

Is the following code valid?

```
var i;
var objs={};
for (i=0; i <10; i++)
{
   objs.i=new FooObject();
}

alert(objs.4.someMethod());
```

If not, how should it be rewritten to accomplish what I want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should edit your code as following:

```
var i;
var objs = {};
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  objs[i] = new FooObject();
}

alert(objs[4].someMethod());
```

Comment: If the indexes are close to each other, and you never plan to use anything other than numerical values as keys, you could replace `var objs = {};` with `var objs = [];`. It would be cleaner.

Comment: They won't be close to each other, the for loop i used in my question was just to get the point across. The index can be irregular and random..

Answer (score 2):

```
var i; 
var objs = new Array();

for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
   objs.push(new FooObject());
}


objs[4].someMethod();
```

Comment: I don't want to use push because the numbers may not be in perfect ascending order. After 0-4, 5 and 6 may be missing and the next number may be 7. Can you rewrite it according to that?

Comment: Can you provide a little more detail, I'm confused.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use numericals for variable names <sup>1</sup>. If you want to reference an item by a numerical value, use an array <sup>2</sup>. You can then access items by their key in the array. If you want to cycle through, you can use the `for...in` option <sup>3</sup>. It won't matter if your keys are sequential and contiguous:

```
var x;
var myItems = new Array();
myItems[0] = "Foo";
myItems[9] = "Bar";
myItems[5] = "Fiz";

for (x in myItems) {
  alert(myItems[x]);
}
```

<sup>1</sup> http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_variables.asp
<sup>2</sup> http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_array.asp
<sup>3</sup> http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_array_for_in

Comment: He's not using them for variable names but for property names; this is perfectly valid but they must be referenced using the syntax "objs[4].someMethod()" - although he wouldn't then have useful things like a magic length property and the various array instance methods, which means that he's better off using an array as you say :-)

Comment: I can't use arrays because while I'm using numericals, they won't be in perfect order, they may start with 10, then 5 chunks may be missing and next element may be 15. Arrays wont work like that.

Comment: Really? I can have irregularly named array indexes? I think javascript didn't use to like those

Comment: @Click Upvote - You will only run itno a problem if you try to guess the key values, like in an for(i = 0; i < myarray.length; i++) alert(myarray[i]); In this case you may request an index that doesn't exist.

Comment: What if the array starts with a value greater than 0? Will it still work?

Comment: Yes                            .

Answer (score 1):

You can't use numbers as variable names, because straight up numbers exist as their own object set in Javascript (i.e, you could think of 4 as already being a global variable that you can't override).